# Couldn't Attach File - Android

Tags: android, email, attachment

I want to send my SQLite DB as e-mail. I export my DB file to external storage. When I click the send button, Gmail UI opening and gives a message 'Couldn't file attach'. How do I fix it?

```
final ImageButton syncbutton = findViewById(R.id.syncbtn);
    syncbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            exportToSD();
            String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

            PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
            File Root= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String filelocation=Root.getAbsolutePath() +"/ODB.db";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "info@blabla.com");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mydate);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Lorem Ipsum");
            Uri attachments = Uri.parse(filelocation);
            intent.setData(attachments);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachments);
            intent.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```